# For an Oracle NUMBER datatype, LIKE operator vs BETWEEN..AND operator

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume **mytable** is an Oracle table and it has a field called **id**.  The datatype of **id** is NUMBER(8).  Compare the following queries:

```
select * from mytable where id like '715%'
```

and

```
select * from mytable where id between 71500000 and 71599999
```

I would think the second is more efficient since I think "number comparison" would require fewer number of assembly language instructions than "string comparison".  I need a confirmation or correction.  Please confirm/correct and throw any further comment related to either operator.

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention 1 important piece of info.  **id** in this case must be an 8-digit number.

Comment: What do your tests show?

Comment: Thinking at the level of assembly language instructions is unnecessary.  First think at the level of the Oracle execution plan -- there will be sufficient differences there to indicate that the second version is likely to perform better.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like the execution plan on the second query is more efficient.

The first query is doing a full table scan of the id's, whereas the second query is not.

My Test Data:

Execution Plan of first query:

[image]

Execution Plan of second query:

[image]

Comment: Under the covers, the difference is that the first query has to implicitly convert each `id` value from a number to a string before evaluating the `LIKE` condition.  This renders the index unusable.  If the column was not indexed, both versions would likely use a full table scan, but the first version would still have added overhead of a type conversion for every row.

Answer (score 7):

If you only want values between 71500000 and 71599999 then yes the second one is much more efficient. The first one would also return values between 7150-7159, 71500-71599 etc. and so forth. You would either need to sift through unecessary results or write another couple lines of code to filter the rest of them out. The second option is definitely more efficient for what you seem to want to do.

Comment: The first one would also return 715.

Comment: You're completely right.  I forgot to mention 1 important piece of info.  In my case, id is an 8-digit number.

Comment: If my answer is sufficient for you please select it as your answer so that the question can be marked as answered! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea of using LIKE with a numeric column.
Also, it may not give the results you are looking for.
If you have a value of 715000000, it will show up in the query result, even though it is larger than 71599999.

Also, I do not like between on principle.
If a thing is between two other things, it should not include those two other things. But this is just a personal annoyance.
I prefer to use >= and <= This avoids confusion when I read the query. In addition, sometimes I have to change the query to something like >= a and < c. If I started by using the between operator, I would have to rewrite it when I don't want to be inclusive.

Harv

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other points raised, using LIKE in the manner you suggest would cause Oracle to not use any indexes on the ID column due to the implicit conversion of the data from number to character, resulting in a full table scan when using LIKE versus and index range scan when using BETWEEN. Assuming, of course, you have an index on ID. Even if you don't, however, Oracle will have to do the type conversion on each value it scans in the LIKE case, which it won't have to do in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use math function, otherwise you have to use to_char function to use like, but it will cause performance problems.

select * from mytable where floor(id /100000) = 715
or
select * from mytable where floor(id /100000) = TO_NUMBER('715') // this is parametric